# regex question. How to remove the last "<br>" in a string

Tags: java, regex

How can I remove the last `<br>` in a string that looks like

```
123 Address Street<br> Queens land<br>
London<br> <br> <br>
```

the last 
 isnt neccesarely always the 5th. It can be the second, third etc

I need a regex for replaceAll() or replaceFirst()

EDIT: removed postcode

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any kind of search-for-last function in Java? To be honest, regexes sound like overkill for this.

Comment: Consider not using `<br>` tag at all. See css zen garden for inspiration.

Comment: Obligatory reference, check the answer that has nearly 5000 votes (yup, nearly 5K votes ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Answer (score 10):

Use [String.lastIndexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to tell you the index at which it starts, you can then cut it out yourself.

Comment: +1 for using API and not having to use regexes (which are pretty overkill as Thom Smmith says).

Comment: isn't the index the position of a single charater. lastIndexOf("<br>") returns 45 for me. is 45 the position of "<" only?

Answer (score 1):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("((<br[^>*]>\\s*)+)<br[^>*]>","$1");
```

Note: this doesn't do exactly what you requested, instead it removes the last `<br>` from a group of more than one `<br>` tags, separated by optional whitespace. In your scenario, the result is the same, but there may be other scenarios.

If you just want to get rid of the last `<br>`, you can just do this:

```
String newStr = str.replaceFirst("(.*)<br[^>*]>","$1");
```

Comment: none of those work. i still get "123 Address Street<br> Queens land<br>
London<br> <br>"

Comment: @Dave but that's exactly what you asked for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?smi)<br\\s*/?>(?!\\<br).*?$", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

one of these

```
"(?s)<br>(?=((?!<br>).)*$)"   or    "<br>(?=((?!<br>)[\\S\\s])*$)"
```