# regex how do i remove the last "<br>" in a string

Tags: java, regex

How can i remove the last `<br>` from a string with replace() or replaceAll()

the `<br>` comes after either a `<br>` or a word

my idea is to add a string to the end of a string and then it'll be `<br>` +my added string

how can i replace it then?

Comment: Does it have to be using replaceAll and regex? If so, is it homework?

Comment: @GolezTrol i'd just rather is is replace or replaceAll so i dont have to add more code. i know it can be done with regex. no its not homework

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171120/regex-question-how-to-remove-the-last-br-in-a-string

Comment: @lwburk that issue is solved. it was to remove all <br> escept one. this is to remove the last br

Comment: @user521180 - Um, no. The question there is "How can I remove the last <br> in a string", which is exactly your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexp is probably not the best for this kind of task. also check answers to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171120/397667).
Looking for `<br>` you could also find `<BR>` or `<br />`

```
String str = "ab <br> cd <br> 12";
String res = str.replaceAll( "^(.*)<br>(.*)$", "$1$2" );
// res = "ab <br> cd 12"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to replace the last `<br />` which might not be the last thing in the string, you could use something like this.

```
String replaceString = "<br />";
String str = "fdasfjlkds <br /> fdasfds <br /> dfasfads";
int ind = str.lastIndexOf(replaceString);
String newString = str.substring(0, ind - 1)
        + str.substring(ind + replaceString.length());
System.out.println(newString);
```

Output

```
fdasfjlkds <br /> fdasfds> dfasfads
```

Ofcourse, you'll have to add some checks to to avoid NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Not using `replace`, but does what you want without a regex:

```
String s = "blah blah <br>";

if (s.endsWith("<br>")) {
   s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, it would be:

```
theString.replaceAll("<br>$", "");
```